# MySQL inserts holding locks on unrelated tables

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

I'm getting this strange deadlock from MySQL:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2300749061, ACTIVE 1 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1

INSERT INTO `event_entities` ( `entity_id`, `event_id`) VALUES ( '16011341', '8064913' )
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 38454477 page no 22728 n bits 640 index `event_id` of table `event_entities` trx id 2300749061 lock mode S waiting
*** (2) TRANSACTION:
INSERT INTO `account_entities` ( `entity_id`, `account_id`) VALUES ( '16093815', '4590372' )
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 38454477 page no 22728 n bits 640 index `event_id` of table `event_entities` trx id 2300748502 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 38454560 page no 21704 n bits 896 index `account_id` of table `account_entities` trx id 2300748502 lock mode S waiting
*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

Here's what those tables look like:

```
CREATE TABLE `event_entities` (
  `event_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `entity_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`,`entity_id`),
  KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `event_entities_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `events` (`event_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `event_entities_fk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `entities` (`entity_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE `account_entities` (
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `entity_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`,`entity_id`),
  KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `account_entities_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`account_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `account_entities_fk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `entities` (`entity_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

I don't get why the insert into account_entities is holding a lock on event_entities, but I'm sure it has something to do with both tables having a FK to entities. Can anyone explain what might be going on?

Comment: Deadlocks occur when there are multiple lock requests that occur out of order and end up waiting for locks previously acquired by each other. I would infer that your transaction (2) had previously done some locking operation on `event_entities` and still holds that lock.

Comment: Show us all the SQL in each of the transactions.  Then it will be easier to point to what is out of order, or whether it is something else.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely an earlier query in transaction 2 that is creation lock on index `event_id` of table `event_entities`.

Please enable general_log and post the all SQL statements in the transactions.